# Show DIV on different part of page

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a C# ASP.Net web forms application and we are using Bootstrap 4.  Based on some criteria, I would like to show a div in a different section of the page.  For example, if Jill is logged in, I want to show some data related to her department on the right side of the page.  Everything else is on the left.  If Pete is logged in, his department's info should show on the right.  Otherwise, all other data is on the left.

I'm open to suggestions and things to search for.  Tried Cards, Panels, etc.

[image: Jill logged in]

If Pete Logged in...

[image: Pete logged in]

Comment: Where is this data coming from and how are you binding it to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two sections, I recommend using two cards:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/

For the colleagues boxes, the custom content list group seems adapted:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/list-group/#custom-content

https://codepen.io/dpamonty/pen/YzXLGbY

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        Section A
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
              <h5 class="mb-1">Bob</h5>
              <small class="text-muted">Other useful info</small>
            </div>
            <p class="mb-1">Bob's stuff here.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
              <h5 class="mb-1">Jill</h5>
              <small class="text-muted">Other useful info</small>
            </div>
            <p class="mb-1">Jill's stuff here.</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        Section B
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
              <h5 class="mb-1">Pete</h5>
              <small>Other useful info</small>
            </div>
            <p class="mb-1">Pete's stuff here.</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

To make everything dynamic, a nice option could be Vue.js, if you are familiar with it. It is very convenient for binding data to the DOM in an elegant and simple fashion. You only have to write the code of one single div per section and bind the data using a v-for attribute. In this example, the logged-on/off colleagues are refreshed every second (`setInterval()` function). I recommend to use Ajax to retrieve your logged-on/off colleagues and implement the retrieval methods with ASP.NET `[WebMethod]` in the code behind.

New CodePen with dynamic content:

https://codepen.io/dpamonty/pen/RwPyojq

References:

[Web methods](https://forums.asp.net/t/1966118.aspx?How+to+create+a+Webmethod+that+returns+an+object+as+JSON+format)

[Ajax using Axios in the Vue methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html)

Comment: OK, thanks for the quick response.  I'm looking into the links you sent, especially the List Groups with Custom content.  This sections will have different inputs and data based on department requirements.  Trying to prevent writing different page for each department since the code will be the same.

Comment: If Jill logs in instead of Pete, how do I get Jills inputs to appear in section B and then Pete's inputs to appear in Section A?  I can get everything to show on the page, inputs work, etc.  Just not clear on how to have a "div" appear within different sections.

Comment: Good Morning..  This looks like it could work and I really appreciate your time.